# How to make SQL Server backup in Laravel?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, backup

I try to do backup to my SQL Server databases in App as its explained in Microsoft.
It's executing, I see the Dumpfile on disk as I have named it and it disappears after a few seconds. And no error appear. I do it by different ways all of its give the same result.
this is the Microsoft link: https://learn.microsoft.com/ar-sa/archive/blogs/brian_swan/backup-and-restore-a-database-with-the-sql-server-driver-for-php
I had run it by routes and controller, and by PHP code and JavaScript, all of them do the same .
This is the PHP code:

```
   $backup_file = "d:\backup\TestDB_Backup.bak";
   $sql = "BACKUP DATABASE Mydatabase TO DISK = '".$backup_file."'";
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Mydatabase","TrustServerCertificate"=>"True", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
   $conn=sqlsrv_connect( ".", $connectionInfo);
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

SQL Server Version 2017, Laravel V9

Comment: We can't see what's happening on your computer from here. Can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75122224/edit) your question to include the link(s) to the Microsoft material you're reading, as well as include the code you're attempting to use - as text, not images?

Comment: I don't know anything about Laravel, but you you must process all of the messages returned from BACKUP.  If you close the connection before doing that the backup will be canceled.  However you retrieve multiple resultsets in Laravel, do that.

Comment: there is no result in Laravel

Comment: One thing to try... in the linked blog post you'll notice there's a whole block of code after calling `sqlsrv_query(...)` starting with `if($stmt === false)`... what happens if you append that code to your code? Does it print a meaningful error message?

Comment: Also pay attention to the discussion of `WarningsReturnAsErrors` immediately before that code sample. The `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` statements output progress messages with `Severity 0` while processing which the `sqlsrv` driver may interpret as warning messages and, due to this setting, therefore interpret as errors.

Comment: this is the error :   array (
    0 => '01000',
    'SQLSTATE' => '01000',
    1 => 4035,
    'code' => 4035,
    2 => '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Processed 1544 pages for database \'DB_TKSET\', file \'DB_TKSET_1\' on file 1.',
    'message' => '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Processed 1544 pages for database \'DB_TKSET\', file \'DB_TKSET_1\' on file 1.',
  )